# neighbours in 2dm matrix represented as list of list

Tags: haskell

Well I can't figure out how I could make it in haskell. For example, I have such matrix

```
[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

and I want to generate a list of lists with all possible neighbours of each element for this matrix.

Expected result is:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,1],[2,3],[2,4],[3,1],[3,2],[3,4],[4,1],[4,2],[4,3]]
```

I know how to make function which will create list of list with cords of neighbours of each cell:

```
pos how = [ (0+dx,0+dy) | dx <- [0..(how-2)], dy <- [0..how-1] ] :: [(Int,Int)]
neighbour (x,y) how = [ (x+dx,y+dy) | dy <- [-1..1], dx <- [-1..1],
                                      x+dx >= 0, y+dy >= 0, x+dx<=how-2, y+dy <= how-1,
                                      (x,y)/=(x+dx,y+dy) ] :: [(Int,Int)]
all_n how = [ p | x <- pos how, let p = neighbour x how ] :: [[(Int,Int)]]
```

but I can't change it to work as I described.

Comment: It's really hard to work out what you're asking at the moment. Can you be a bit more clear? For example, how do you define a "neighbour"? Why is `[1,4]` included in your list of expected results?

Comment: if cell touch other even with corner is her neighbour

Comment: Then why is `[1,4]` in your list of expected results? It's not a neighbour of `[1,2]` or of `[3,4]`.

Comment: 1 touch 4 with its corners oi48.tinypic.com/20sc20n.jpg dont You see it ?

Comment: Ok, I got it now. You should edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me sketch a very different approach to the one you suggested. When talking about neighbors, I'll say a *d*-neighbor of *e* is the element one step in direction *d* from element *e*. So, for example, in the matrix `[[1,2],[3,4]]`, the number `2` is a right-neighbor of number `1`. We'll need to use some library code.

```
import Data.List
```

We'll start from the very simplest thing: let's just find right-neighbors of a one-dimensional list.

```
rightList (x:y:rest) = (x,y) : rightList (y:rest)
rightList _ = []
```

We can find all the right-neighbors in a matrix by nondeterministically choosing a row of the matrix and finding all right-neighbors in that row.

```
right m = m >>= rightList
```

We can take any function for finding neighbors and create the function for finding neighbors in the other direction by reversing the tuples. For example, left neighbors are the same as right neighbors, but with the tuple elements swapped, so:

```
swap (x,y) = (y,x)
co direction = map swap . direction
left = co right
```

What about down-neighbors? Actually, down-neighbors are just right-neighbors in the transposed matrix:

```
down = right . transpose
up   = co down
```

The next direction of interest are down-right-neighbors. This one is a little trickier; what we're going to do is walk down two lists in parallel, but offset by one.

```
downRight (xs:ys:rest) = zip xs (drop 1 ys) ++ downRight (ys:rest)
downRight _            = []
upLeft = co downRight
```

There's one final direction, namely up-right-neighbors; these are down-right-neighbors if we flip the matrix upside down.

```
upRight  = downRight . reverse
downLeft = co upRight
```

Finally, to form all neighbors, we can nondeterministically choose a neighboring direction, then find all neighbors in that direction.

```
allDirections = [right, left, up, down,
                 downRight, upLeft, upRight, downLeft]
neighbors m = allDirections >>= ($m)
```

The output isn't in exactly the order you specified, but I imagine this may not matter so much.

Answer (score 1):

To correct the code you have now, I provide a few questions for which a thoughtful answer may help you make progress:

- `how-2` is a strange thing. Why is `2` the right number to subtract?
- The type of `all_n` is quite strange. Why is it a function? (What does its argument represent?) Why does it return a nested list, rather than a flat one?
- It seems you're tracking only one size parameter, but your matrix is a two-dimensional matrix. Why is there such a discrepancy? (Why don't you have both a width and height parameter?)
- Once you have a coordinate, do you know how to fetch the element at that position from the matrix? (Hint: there is a function `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> [a]`.) If you have a list of coordinates, do you know how to do this for each element in the list? (Hint: there is a function `map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])`.)

Good luck!

Comment: -1 becouse !! starts from 0 and next -1 becouse its n/n-1 matrix

Comment: @whd I'm sure you know the problem better than I do, but `[[1,2],[3,4]]` sure doesn't *look* like an nx(n-1) matrix.

Comment: i know but it was easiest way to show what i mean and your functions will also works with other matrix